# Does the OpenFileDialog class normally show an icon? How to set?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the past, I thought that the OpenFileDialog class normally wouldn't show an form icon in the upper left hand corner but I am seeing the default form icon now. I have seen other posts that say that there is no icon but I am seeing one with the following code.

```
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();            
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Project";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "File2Table Project (*.f2tproj)|*.f2tproj|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
```

How do I set it to a better icon or remove it?

Comment: I think it depends on whether you call `OpenDialog()` or `OpenDialog(IWin32Window owner)` - if you call the `owner` version then it will inherit the icon of the parent window, otherwise no icon. I may be incorrect.

Comment: It simply duplicates the icon of its owner window.  A dialog always has an owner, even if you don't explicitly use the ShowDialog(owner) overload.  Always avoid a scenario where it cannot find one and has to pick the desktop window as the owner, too easy for the dialog to disappear behind another window.

Comment: @ChadD did you ever solve this?

Comment: @c-chavez  no, i did not solve it

Comment: @ChadD I'm running the same problem, and the only thing I have found out is that if the parent has an icon, or shows an icon, the OpenFileDialog will show it. If you disable it on the parent, then the dialog won't show it. But in my case I have to show it in the parent and not in the dialog... so I'm still running on this problem :(